# Only keep the month of a date column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark, and I want to only keep the month of my date column.

This is the format of my column for example: "2022-07-25" (string format).
I want to create a new column into my dataset with just "07" for this example.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
F.date_format("date_col", "MM")
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("2022-07-25",)], ["date_col"])

df = df.withColumn("date_col", F.date_format("date_col", "MM"))

df.show()
# +--------+
# |date_col|
# +--------+
# |07      |
# +--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can additionally use [month](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.month.html) from pyspark & lpad if required

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
date_str
2022-03-01 13:59:50
2022-05-20 13:45:50
2022-06-21 16:59:50
2022-10-22 20:59:50
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter=',')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)\
             .withColumn('date_parsed',F.to_timestamp(F.col('date_str'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))\
             .drop('date_str')

sparkDF.show()

+-------------------+
|        date_parsed|
+-------------------+
|2022-03-01 13:59:50|
|2022-05-20 13:45:50|
|2022-06-21 16:59:50|
|2022-10-22 20:59:50|
+-------------------+
```

#### Extract Month

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn("date_month", F.month("date_parsed"))

sparkDF.show()

+-------------------+----------+
|        date_parsed|date_month|
+-------------------+----------+
|2022-03-01 13:59:50|         3|
|2022-05-20 13:45:50|         5|
|2022-06-21 16:59:50|         6|
|2022-10-22 20:59:50|        10|
+-------------------+----------+
```